# Ubuntu corrupted!

Tags: system, settings

[image][image]

No settings are working in my Ubuntu Desktop. No themes, no launcher icons size, no font size nothing at all. Have had I deleted the important system file? Seeking help

Below is the screenshot of my desktop. As you can see that the launher icon size is lowest(16) and the theme has been set to "High Contrast" still no changes, everything is default.

As you can see even after changing the desktop environment I can't solve the setting issue. The global 'dark theme' has been set up in the tweak-tool but still everything is set to default

Answer (score 1):

So try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop`. If it doesn't work, remove also global configurations (I don't know if `--reinstall` does this already) with `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Its of no use @Peter Nerlich, any other options?http://askubuntu.com/users/329400/peter-nerlich

Comment: Hm, if you are fine with giving up on the unity environment, try another display manager like **GNOME** or **KDE**, **XFC**, **LXDE**...
-> `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`
/ `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`
/ `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`
/ `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Ok! about that but how to solve my partition issue. Other partitions are too not showing except the "/" one.